# (Linux Mint) Is it possible to create a desklet o applet that shows an html iframe content?

Tags: html, applet, embed, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon and i wish to create an desktop application (desklet or applet) that shows html embed content, like mp3 player for example, is possible to do it? 
Thanks for responses.

Comment: Still after 5 years, the desklets are pretty basic. Html iframe content is not available and it would be great to have. Another great feature would be to make the desklet resizable via mouse.